# Add active class to "div" based on URL

Tags: jquery, html

My code only add active class to "a" i want this code add active class to the "div"

This is my Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
var path = window.location.href; 
element is the absolute path
$('ul a div').each(function() {
    if (this.href === path) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
});
```

And this is my HTML code

```
<a href="?a=home"><div class="menu">Home</div></a>
<a href="?a=work"><div class="menu">Work</div></a>
```

I want active class add to the div not to "a" !!

Comment: change $(this).addClass('active') to $(this).children().addClass('active') ?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
$('ul a div').each(function () {
     if ($(this).parent().prop("href") === path) {
         $(this).addClass('active');
     }
 });
```